# Google App Script giving #ERROR when accessing IMPORTHTML function in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that basically acesses all the values in a spreadsheet. From time to time, it changes it behavior when it comes to accessing data from the spreadsheet where the IMPORTHTML function is being used. What's weird is that the data is shown properly in the sheet, but when accessed through app script, the first cell from the data gives #ERROR.

It seems like some kind of a refresh issue. Most of the time, it works, and sometimes, it breaks and I have to re-enter the formula in the cell to refresh. How do I go about fixing this so it doesn't randomly break my code?

Simply accessing data in app script like this:

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_ID);

var sheet = spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Example SheetName'));

var data = spreadsheet.getDataRange().getValues();
```

AND in sheets, I have something like this in the first cell of a sheet:
`=IMPORTHTML("https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/html-tables-table-tutorial-with-css-example-code/","table",1)`

If I try to re-enter/change the value in the spreadsheet directly, it starts to work again. I'm not sure how often I need to be doing it though and that's not a reliable solution

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and some data that will reproduce the problem. Also please provide the exact error

Comment: Edited the post. Hopefully, it's better now.